# how do i print a rectangle with numbers?

Tags: python

i need help making a number rectangle. the width and length are whatever the user inputs but idk how to make the output. it needs to look like this for example:
width = 6, length = 4

```
654321
654321
654321
654321
```

this is what i have:

```
def drawnumberrectangle():
    height = getinteger("Enter a height: ")
    width = getinteger("Enter a width: ")
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < height:
        while j < width:
            print()
            j = j + 1
        print("")
        j = 0
        i = i + 1
```

i need something in the print function

Answer (score 1):

Note that, for every line, the numbers goes from `width` to 1.

```
''.join([str(x) for x in range(width, 0, -1)])
```

#### Explanation

- `range(width, 0, -1)` generates a iterable of numbers going from `width` down to 1.
- `[str(x) for x in range(width, 0, -1)]` turns the previous range into a string list.
- `''.join([str(x) for x in range(width, 0, -1)])` joins the strings of that list in a single string.

Also note that this line repeats `length` times.

```
for i in range(length):
    print(''.join([str(i) for i in range(width, 0, -1)]))
```

Here is your code.

Comment: You could also do `reversed(range(width))`

Comment: And another way to reverse is `[::-1]`

Comment: And you don't need the square brackets if you're passing it to a function right away. `''.join(str(i) for i in reversed(range(width)))` a generator expression will work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your counter

```
def drawnumberrectangle():
    height = getinteger("Enter a height: ")
    width = getinteger("Enter a width: ")
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < height:
        while j < width:
            print(width-j)
            j = j + 1
        print("")
        j = 0
        i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
height = input("Enter a height: ")
width = input("Enter a width: ")
i = int(height)
while i > 0:
    j=int(width)
    while j > 0:
        print(j, end="")
        j = j - 1
    print("")
    i = i - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(width - j, end="")` should do it. What this does is print out `width - j` on each iteration, so it will start at the width (since j=0 at the beginning) and go down to one (since it will be width-1 at the last iteration).

`end=""` tells `print(...)` to add an empty string at the end instead of a new line character so that it prints the next character at the same line. Your `print("")` further down will print out the new line once it's done printing the numbers.

```
def drawnumberrectangle():
    height = getinteger("Enter a height: ")
    width = getinteger("Enter a width: ")
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < height:
        while j < width:
            print(width - j, end="")
            j = j + 1
        print("")
        j = 0
        i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print every number individually, you'll get a line break after each one. Instead, you could construct a line string, and then print that:

```
def drawnumberrectangle():
    height = getinteger("Enter a height: ")
    width = getinteger("Enter a width: ")
    for i in range(height):
        line = ''
        for j in range(width):
            line += '{}'.format(width - j)
        print(line)
```

I also changed it to use `for in` loops and `range`, which is more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to python. Here we have a few funky constructs that save a lot of typing. As you can see, this can be done in far fewer lines than some other languages.

Then `range()` function will provide you a list of integers. In the line that sets the height, I pass it how many lines we're going to need. In the width, you can see I specified `range(1, width +1)`. This is because `range()` by default starts at 0, but we needed to actually print `"1"`.

The next trick is the list comprehension `[str(w) for w in range(1, width+1)]`. This will create a list of characters. But since we're going to print them, I convert them to a string. This is because `''.join()` will group them all into one nice string.

The final trick is the part where you see `[::-1]` which is taking a slice of the list. There are three arguments, start, stop, and step, which are separated by the colons. Blanks mean start at the beginning and end at the end. The step of `-1` means do everything backwards.

```
def rectangle(width, height):

    for h in range(height):
        print(''.join([str(w) for w in range(1, width+1)][::-1]))

rectangle(6, 4)
# 654321
# 654321
# 654321
# 654321
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework problem so I'm not going to give too much away. I would suggest you start with a counted loop (for loop) as this will simplify your code, and use the join() method

```
height = getinteger("Enter a height: ")
width = getinteger("Enter a width: ")

for i in range(height):
    print(''.join([str(j) for j in range(width,1,-1)]))
```

To explain these constructs, the join() method joins the argument passed using the string it is called on as the separator e.g. if we wanted to separate the numbers with commas we would use `','.join(numberList)`. The second thing you'll see if the list comprehension - this creates a list given a condition. In this case, we want a list of all the numbers that are from a to b, with a step of -1 (counting down) so we use `range(6,1,-1)` and we want those numbers as a string, so we do a type conversion using `str(j)`

Comment: Good point, when running from interpreter I didn't need to print it, forgot to add that here